# I have used stepstone rating dialogue.I would like to set Positive or Negative button disable with some condittion

Tags: android

This is basically the stepstone ratingDialog which i have compiled for my rating..I would like to disable the neutral or negative button like setEnabled false if certain condition is not made.How do i set the button positive or negative setEnabled false?

```
private void showRatingDialog() {
 new AppRatingDialog.Builder()
            .setPositiveButtonText("Submit")
            .setNegativeButtonText("Cancel")
            .setNeutralButtonText("Upload Image")
            .setNoteDescriptions(Arrays.asList("Not Satisfied","Not Bad","Normal Place","Good Place","Must Visit"))
            .setTitle("Rate this location")
            .setDescription("Please give some rating and  feedback")
            .setDefaultRating(1)
            .setStarColor(R.color.colorPrimary)
            .setNoteDescriptionTextColor(R.color.colorPrimary)
            .setTitleTextColor(R.color.colorAccent)
            .setDescriptionTextColor(R.color.colorAccent)
            .setHint("Please write your comment here ")
            .setHintTextColor(R.color.colorPrimary)
            .setCommentTextColor(R.color.colorPrimary)
            .setCommentBackgroundColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)
            .setWindowAnimation(R.style.MyDialogFadeAnimation)
            .create(LocationDetails.this)
            .show();


}


 @Override
public void onNegativeButtonClicked() {


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [StepStone RatingDialog](https://github.com/stepstone-tech/android-material-app-rating) it has a condition on setting the buttons.

```
private fun setupNeutralButton(builder: AlertDialog.Builder) {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(neutralButtonText)) {
        builder.setNeutralButton(neutralButtonText) { dialog, which ->
            listener?.onNeutralButtonClicked()
        }
    }
}
```

Try `.setNeutralButtonText("")`